# How to fix: 'Trying to access array offset on value of type null' Error and 413

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-livewire

I'm encountering the error

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null.

And it prints the following error to the console

```
/livewire/upload-file?expires=1703146593&signature=2957b831764ba772e5ba5707167b7eeae7e464a8565e04eef693bc4e9da0e27b:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 ().
```

I've tried following Google's suggestion by adjusting the php.ini as follows and using `phpinfo()`, which returns the following:

```
memory_limit    9999M   9999M
max_execution_time  36000   36000
max_file_uploads    2000    2000
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  -1  -1
max_input_vars  1000    1000
upload_max_filesize 9999M   9999M
upload_tmp_dir  9999M   9999M
post_max_size   9999M   9999M
```

However, the error persists. I am using Linux - PHP 8.2 - Livewire-Laravel - NGINX. When I run it on localhost, everything works fine, but when deployed on Linux, I encounter this issue. Please help me.

Comment: You should likely try to fix the `Trying to access array offset on value of type null` PHP error in your code first

Comment: You need also check the nginx config related to body size.

Comment: @LF00 I tried using the server {
client_max_body_size 2000M;
client_body_timeout 999s;
} but it didn't work

Comment: @Olivier But on localhost, there is no error at all? I just selected a 20MB video, and it threw that error. Haven't done anything else. But when I choose a 64KB video, it's normal

Comment: You still need to know which line causes the error. That's the first step.

Comment: Are you also using nginx on localhost?

Comment: After you edit config, have you reload the service?